# Sorting: How to create a particular custom order, then alphabetic sort in java

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, comparator

I have an Enum with around 70 fields.

I want 10 of them to be displayed in a particular order, then I want the rest to be displayed alphabetically using a Comparator. I have tried many things, but I can't get it to work.

Here is a sample enum with reduces attributes
**I want Picard, Worf and William to display first, then the rest alphabetically**

I cannot use any third libraries. It must be java core. So if you want to provide guava answers, or apache commons answer, please do so in addition to java core.

```
public enum StarTrek {

    JeanLucPicard("Picard"),
    GeordiLaForge("Geordi"),
    DiannaTroi("Dianna"),
    Worf("Worf"),
    WilliamRiker("William"),
    Q("Q");

    private String label;

    StarTrek(String label) { this.label = label; }

    @Override public String toString() { return label; }
}

    List<StarTrek> specificOrder = Arrays.asList(StarTrek.JeanLucPicard, StarTrek.Worf, StarTrek.WilliamRiker);

    Comparator<StarTrek> comp = new Comparator<StarTrek>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(StarTrek o1, StarTrek o2) {
                //TODO: loop through the specific order, and display those first, then for the rest, go alphabetic
                return 0;
            }
    };

    List<StarTrek> all = Arrays.asList(StarTrek.values());
    Collections.sort(all, comp);
```

Comment: Why not do it in two steps ?

Comment: I have solved it by not using sort, and just removing and adding in the collection, but I want to solve it using sort. its much nicer. I also only want to call sort once

Comment: I'm not so sure it's nicer. Two steps would be more readable to me and stops you from polluting your enum class with meta data required only for display.

Comment: In that case do as others suggested.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is bad design to place additional data in your enum just for the purposes of displaying in a particular order. Instead, place all that logic in your `Comparator`, as shown below:

```
public class StarTrekSorter implements Comparator<StarTrek> {

  private static final List<StarTrek> ORDERED_ENTRIES = Arrays.asList(
      StarTrek.JeanLucPicard, StarTrek.Worf, StarTrek.WilliamRiker);

  @Override
  public int compare(StarTrek o1, StarTrek o2) {
    if (ORDERED_ENTRIES.contains(o1) && ORDERED_ENTRIES.contains(o2)) {
      // Both objects are in our ordered list. Compare them by
      // their position in the list
      return ORDERED_ENTRIES.indexOf(o1) - ORDERED_ENTRIES.indexOf(o2);
    }

    if (ORDERED_ENTRIES.contains(o1)) {
      // o1 is in the ordered list, but o2 isn't. o1 is smaller (i.e. first)
      return -1;
    }

    if (ORDERED_ENTRIES.contains(o2)) {
      // o2 is in the ordered list, but o1 isn't. o2 is smaller (i.e. first)
      return 1;
    }

    return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
  }
}
```

Now, you can just sort:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  List<StarTrek> cast = Arrays.asList(StarTrek.values());

  Collections.sort(cast, new StarTrekSorter());

  for (StarTrek trek : cast) {
    System.out.println(trek);
  }  
}
```

which prints

```
Picard
Worf
William
Dianna
Geordi
Q
```

Comment: Could you please explain step by step what is going on? Its hard to understand this comparator

Comment: @Shervin I've added some comments to try and help. `compare` methods are always difficult to wrap your head around.

Comment: @DuncanJones Thanks. It helped. Still find it quite difficult though :)

Comment: @Shervin I found it difficult to write! The Javadocs for `compare` are not the easiest to read. Sometimes it's easiest to just experiment with a small set of values to be sure the ordering is as you expect.

Comment: Well I appreciate you took the time to do it for me!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
JeanLucPicard("Picard", 0),
GeordiLaForge("Geordi"),
DiannaTroi("Dianna"),
Worf("Worf", 1),
WilliamRiker("William", 2),
Q("Q");

StarTrek(String label) { this(label, -1); }
StarTrek(String label, int orderHint) { this.label=label; this.orderHint=orderHint; }
```

And in the `compare` method something like this:

```
if (orderHint == -1) {
   return o1.label.compareTo(o2.label));
}
return o2.orderHint-o1.orderHint;
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way other than changing my enum implementation?

Answer (score 1):

List the enums you want special ordering for first in your list, then use this code:

```
Comparator<StarTrek> comp = new Comparator<StarTrek>() {
    public int compare(StarTrek o1, StarTrek o2) {
        if (o1.ordinal() < 3)
            return o2.ordinal() < 3 ? o1.ordinal() - o2.ordinal() : 1;
        return o2.ordinal() < 3 ? -1 : o1.name().compareTo(o2.name());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an additional constructor in your enum, that takes an index parameter, then provide indexes for the instances you want to go first (leave the ones you want to go in alphabetical order unindexed):

```
enum StarTrek {

    JeanLucPicard("Picard"),
    GeordiLaForge("Geordi"),
    DiannaTroi("Dianna"),
    Worf("Worf", 2),
    WilliamRiker("William", 1),
    Q("Q");

    private final String label;
    private final Integer index;

    StarTrek(final String label, final Integer index ) { this.label = label; this.index = index; }

    StarTrek(final String label) { this.label = label; this.index = Integer.MAX_VALUE; }

    @Override public String toString() { return label; }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Then your comparator would have to look like:

```
final Comparator<StarTrek> comp = new Comparator<StarTrek>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(final StarTrek o1, final StarTrek o2) {
                    if (!o1.getIndex().equals(o2.getIndex())) {
                        return o1.getIndex().compareTo(o2.getIndex());
                    }
                    return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
                }
        };
```